# declaring circular singly linked list java

Tags: linked-list, circular-dependency

I would like to use the prepared circular singly linked list class in Java, but I don't know how to declare it. Would you please let me know how to call this class?

I know that we have a class, but I don't know it. Is the class LinkedList circular?

Comment: Wouldn't circular mean only that the next pointer on the last node points to the head?  I don't think that would have much impact on the declaration, except that there wouldn't be a length method.  Maybe edit to show what you've got so far to help give an idea of where the challenge is.

Comment: @danh Exactly. The last node points to the first node. Is the existing class in Java, called "LinkedList" circular? Or, we need to use another class?

Comment: No, it isn't. I think a subclass that changed mainly (only?) the iterator is all that you'd need.  I guess you'd have to work out what the iterator should do, maybe end after on cycle, no matter where it began?

Comment: @danh I know how to write this class, but I was looking for an existing one. Thank you, sir.